# What is a TFS Agile Issue?

Tags: tfs, agile, tfs-process-template

With TFS2010 using the "MSF for Agile Software Development v5" process template, I'm having some difficulty in understanding exactly what an `Issue` is. The most specific documentation I've been able to find is [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380654.aspx). Is an `Issue` a higher-level item for which we will probably generate a `Bug` for after some investigation in code/requirements? Or is an `Issue` something different than a `Bug` because it has not actually a mistake in code but is more of a critical oversight in design (for example, there was never an attempt to create a datepicker for all date fields and this is a UX issue but not really a bug) and therefore a change request of sorts? Or is it something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An issue is a problem.  After investigation it could become a bug in the software, or a task to change the process and code that supports it.

Comment: I agree. An issue might be for example that certificates are about to expire. Another issue might be that multiple components duplicate functionality and incur maintenance costs in the face of change. Another issue might be some specific risk that should be mitigated. All these are top level cross-company or cross-platform requirements that do not map to user stories.

Answer (score 4):

I think Issue == Impediment

Comment: I think an Issue is "anything that should be addressed". These will include complaints from customers, feature requests, and it will also include impediments that need be addressed. If the issue can be addressed directly, it will just be closed. Say it was the room temperature is too cold, you just address the issue and close it by cranking the thermostat higher. If the issue can not be addressed directly, either because it is a bug, or a feature, it must be addressed by creating a bug report or a task to implement the feature. At which point, you can close the issue.